# type 'int' is not a subtype of 'double' flutter even after using toInt()

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, typeerror, subtype

In my app I'm converting a double temp by temp.toInt() to a late int temperature variable. But somehow my app crashes and showing me error saying "type 'int' is not a subtype of 'double'". The main problem is it works suddenly. And then again it crashes. I don't know why it's happening. here is my code-

```
class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  late int temperature;
  late String cityName;
  late String weatherIcon;
  late String weatherMessage;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        temperature = 0;
        weatherIcon = 'Error';
        weatherMessage = 'Unable to get weather data';
        cityName = '';
        return;
      }
      double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      temperature = temp.toInt();
      var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);

      cityName = weatherData['name'];
    });
  }
```

what should I do? please let me know if you have any advice.
Thanks in advance.

I've tried declaring another int variable and assign it to temperature but that didn't work either.

Comment: can you try print(weatherData['main']['temp']) before assigning it to `temp`  and see it's type

Comment: Sometimes it's an integer and another time it's showing a float value.

Comment: I guess I've found it. by 
double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'].toDouble();
it solves the problem. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try making temp as dynamic

```
dynamic temperature;
```

Comment: This avoids the error but disables type-safety, and it does not educate the OP about what is wrong.  This is not a good solution.  If you want to use this approach, at least `num` instead of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the code and the error it seems the error must actually be on this line:

```
  double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
```

Meaning that it already is an int and you can't assign that to the double here

you can probably just directly do

```
  temperature = weatherData['main']['temp'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is sometimes an int, sometimes a double. By converting weatherData['main']['temp'] to a double value -
weatherData['main']['temp'].toDouble();
solves the problem.

Comment: Using `dynamic` disables type-safety and thus suppresses the error, but it is not a good solution.  You also should not make answers that reiterate other people's answers.

Comment: I put the answer that worked for me. I'd definitely remember your advice for future question answers.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use .toInt()

Use

```
temperature = int.parse(temp);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).